# Solspace Facebook Connect: Pop-up window disappears without letting user confirm settings

Tags: solspace, solspace-facebookconnect

Maybe I have this wrong but I thought that if a user is logging in using FBC then the popup window gives them the option of previewing and agreeing to the FB APP requirements. When I click on the login link it's just redirecting to my specified return URL and the connection is made.

Is this an error or am I missing a configuration setting.

Here's my code:

```
{exp:fbc:login
                permissions="email|publish_stream|read_stream"
                return_when_logged_in="account/profile"
                return_when_logged_out="home/index"
                return_to_register="account/register"
                return_on_failure="account/profile/fail"
            }
                {if fbc_logged_out == "y"}
                    {fbc_login_button}
                {/if} 
            {/exp:fbc:login}
```

Comment: It will do that if you're already logged into your facebook account and that facebook account has already granted permissions to your app. If you're testing it with your own account make sure to go into your facebook app preferences and remove the permissions for your app before each test.

Comment: Thanks Benek, deleting the app from my Facebook account did fix the issue.